# Save password for login on another site

Tags: php, authentication, cross-site

We need to make a login system for students of our school.
We need to get information from our schools site and display this on our site.
Our school doesn't have an api or other way to log them in, users need to enter their login credentials.

Now I am aware of post & get requests to log the user in ones I got their password but I need to know if there is a SECURE way for my users to only login to my site and that then we will automatically be able to log into the site of our school.  We do not have any say in how the school stores passwords.  Also, there are multiple people involved so nobody should be able to see any password.

Comment: _nobody should be able to see any password._ Famous last words!

Comment: If I've got this correct, you want to allow students access to the site via their school username/password used for accessing computers. This setup means that the website will in some way have to access the ADC (Active Directory Control) server to check against the user's details; for this I *think* is only possible via using Microsoft's IIS webserver and a C# webapplication, but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only secure way to pass logins between Applications is either [oAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) or [SAML2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) - everything else will compromise either site security in some way.

Comment: Would storing the user credentials on the users device be considered secure?

Answer (score -1):

There are a great deal of tutorials regrading this topic, however I would recommend looking at phpacademy, he gives good explanations as he shows you how to write the code, yes I know linking sites is normally frowned upon but the author on this particular time is fairly reliable and stable.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

Comment: Sadly enough this will not fix my problem. I do not need to know how to make a login system but how to savely store info that needs to be put into another login system.

Comment: You mean use multiple databases? That can be done something like this:

$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);

Then to query database 1 pass the first link identifier:

mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);

and for database 2 pass the second:

mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);